# QuestDb docker compose image

Tags: questdb

What's the image name I should use for docker compose? having some trouble getting it all working

```
Pulling questdb (questdb:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.
Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling questdb (questdb:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for questdb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pull `questdb` but the image needs to be in the format `<org>/<image>`:

```yaml
services:
  questdb:
    image: questdb/questdb
  ...
```

Please find an example docker-compose image in the [following GitHub repository](https://github.com/questdb/questdb-slack-grafana-alerts/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) which shows how to start Grafana and QuestDB networked together